# Bamboo SCP Plugin Throwing Exception When Sending Multiple Files

Tags: scp, bamboo, continuous-deployment

I am using Atlasssian Bamboo version 5.0 build 3715 - 11 Jul 13. I tried adding scp task to my build plan in order to transfer some build artifacts to a remote server. When trying to transfer multiple files (by comma separated list or by ant pattern or the whole directory), I encounter this exception:

net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPException: EOF while expecting response to protocol message

However If I add separate scp task for each file, there is no problem.

I tried to transfer the same files using my local scp client and my local scp client can transfer them to the remote with no problem. I tried with different set of files. Only once bamboo scp plugin could send multiple files. Does anybody know whats the problem?